# FlexSlider - one of regional characters not displaying correctly dispite using compatible font

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, flexslider

**UPDATE:** Now I know it's something wrong with the charset of that flexSlider generated part of code because in source preview this letter is also displayed as a ? icon. Few lines below- outside flexslider- it displayed correctly. Now the question is is that charset is just a charset of .js file? Or is charset set this way inside FlexSlider Javascipt code?
This probably makes whole "css trail" below irrelevant. Problem is I don't have server access. I use WordPress with WPide to edit code. Can I check file encoding somehow (plugin) from wordpess admin interface?

I got a very strange problem. I use flexSlider on my page and today i noticed that one specific regional letter (ą -`&#261;`) is displayed as '?" in a square icon. I can't figure out why. When I was localizing css I just copy pasted font-family line from my page css and replaced the line in `flexslider.css` like that:

```
.flex-caption p {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;    
}
```

In all other places the letter is displayed correctly, the problem is only inside flex slider. I tried different computers, browsers - every time the same error.
I checked the inspector in FF and opera to make sure the css rule is not overridden but when I check "inspect element" -> "computed rules" the font family is what I want it to be - the same as for the rest of the site. How can it work everywhere else but not in this one place? It's making mu nuts! I searched flexslider source for any hard-coded fonts :none

As requested this is my specific implementation, php fragments are wordpress functions

```
<div class="flex-container">
          <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
            <?php $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
              'category_name' => 'featured', 'posts_per_page' => 10
              ));
            ?>
              <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
              <li>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <div class="caption_wrap">
                <div class="flex-caption">
                <div class="flex-caption-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </div>
                <p><?php echo striker_get_slider_excerpt(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">...</a></p>
                </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            <?php
                endwhile;
            ?>
            </ul>
          </div>
</div>
```

relevant css lines,
from flexslider.css:

```
.flex-caption p { width: 500px; padding: 8px; margin: 0; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; word-spacing: 4px; line-height: 1.6;}
.flex-caption-title { font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase; border: 2px solid #FFF; border-radius: 0.2em; font-size: 24px; padding: 0; border-radius: 0.2em; margin: 8px auto; width: 250px; word-spacing: 4px;}
```

and from my page css (the ones I copied working font family from):

```
body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #666;    
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    line-height: 1.9;
}
```

Comment: We would need a minimal working code snippet to be able to help, as just a CSS rule says pretty much nothing

Comment: u can get even a full source here https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider

Comment: If you need compiled css I can post it but I don't see the point in doing that. 88 lines of code will just make my post unreadable. Ihis is one of just two font-family directives there other one is `.flex-caption-title` and it behaves the same

Comment: @LGSon  I'm not the author of flexSlider nor I'm very proficient in JS so I'm totally not competent to fish out relevant fragments and create a snippet. The site that I'm working on is http://jezurkowo.primum.org.pl/ and the slide is titled "Marcin" it uses the same font family inside the post (which is displayed correctly) and inside the slider (which is displayed incorrectly) and I don't have even a vague how this is possible.

Comment: I get that and it is understandable. You could post a link to your site, explaining it is very difficult extracting a small part, along with a small portion of the rendered HTML and its relevant CSS.

Comment: Is the problem still there? I see the right letters (i.e.: "Wesołych Świ**ą**t") in the slides...